# How can I resolve this libwayland-client GLFW Wayland error on NixOS?

Tags: glfw, nixos, zig

I get this error on hyprland nixos when trying to launch a glfw application.

`error: failed to initialize GLFW: Wayland: Failed to load libwayland-client`

Here is my flake.nix:

```hs
{
  description = "";

  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "github:nixos/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
    zig.url = "github:mitchellh/zig-overlay";
  };
  outputs = {nixpkgs, zig, ... } @ inputs:
    let
      system = "x86_64-linux";

      pkgs = import nixpkgs {
        inherit system;
        config.allowUnfree = true;
      };

      zigMaster = zig.packages.${system}.master;
    in
      {
        devShells.${system}.default = pkgs.mkShell {
          BuildInputs = with pkgs; [
            glfw-wayland
          ];
          nativeBuildInputs = [
            zigMaster
          ];
        };
      };
}
```

I really don't know what's causing this problem.

I tried to add wayland-protocols to the BuildInputs, but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: How are you launching the app? Are you starting a shell first then launching your app (ie with `nix shell .`) or are you launching directly (ie with `nix run .`)?

Comment: It's `buildInputs`, not `BuildInputs`. But I don't know if this is enough to fix the issue. I think the problem is that nix cannot find the `libwayland-client.so` library.